# Fixed-width format with commas for summary statistics with estpost summarize in Stata

Tags: stata

The `estpost` and `esttab` commands are from the `estout` package on SSC.

I use `estpost summarize` to make summary statistics tables.
I am told that readers prefer decimals as fixed width/precision.
Say, a leading zero and three decimal places.
Option `fmt(%9.3f)` gives a leading zero and fixed width,
but reports large numbers without commas.
Option `fmt(%12.3gc)` gives commas,
but does not report fixed width decimals.

Is there a way to be more granular with `fmt()` in `esttab`?
Say, use `%12.3gc` for numbers above some threshold and `%9.3f` otherwise?
This may create problems that I have not anticipated.

Here is an example of how I use `estpost summarize` and the shortcomings of each approach.

```
sysuse auto, clear
expand 1000

eststo clear
estpost summarize price rep78, detail
eststo

/* gives mean/median/SD with fixed number of decimals */
/* but must manually add commas to large numbers (price) */
local rightwidth_nocommas ///
    label noobs nonumbers nomtitles ///
    cell("count(fmt(%9.3gc) label(Obs.)) mean(fmt(%9.3f) label(Mean)) p50(fmt(%9.3f) label(Median)) sd(fmt(%9.3f) label(Std. Dev.))")
esttab, `rightwidth_nocommas'

. esttab, `rightwidth_nocommas'

------------------------------------------------------------------------
                             Obs.         Mean       Median    Std. Dev.
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Price                      74,000     6165.257     5006.500     2929.519
Repair Record 1978         69,000        3.406        3.000        0.983
------------------------------------------------------------------------



/* gives commas to large numbers (price) */
/* but must pad mean/median/SD to get a fixed number of decimals */
local commas_wrongwidth ///
    label noobs nonumbers nomtitles ///
    cell("count(fmt(%9.3gc) label(Obs.)) mean(fmt(%9.3gc) label(Mean)) p50(fmt(%9.3gc) label(Median)) sd(fmt(%9.3gc) label(Std. Dev.))")
esttab, `commas_wrongwidth'

. esttab, `commas_wrongwidth'

------------------------------------------------------------------------
                             Obs.         Mean       Median    Std. Dev.
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Price                      74,000        6,165        5,007        2,930
Repair Record 1978         69,000         3.41            3         .983
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: So have you tried something like `%9.3fc` to get numbers with 3 places to the right of the decimal, and commas in large numbers to the left of the decimal?

Comment: @WilliamLisowski Thanks. That (mostly) works in this context. I had tried `%9.3fc` before for `N` in the `stats()` option, but it didn't work (i.e., no comma, but fixed decimal). So for counts, `%9.3fc`  in `esttab` gives `XXXX.XXX` (no comma), but for non-counts, `%9.3fc` in `esttab` gives `X,XXX.XXX`, which is what I want. __TLDR__ use `9.3gc` for counts, `%9.3fc` for everything else.

Comment: @WilliamLisowski if you'd like the reputation, then make this an answer and I will mark as correct. Otherwise, I can answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a demo using `fc` for everything, no `gc` needed for counts, and using a set of surrounding parentheses instead of quotation marks around the argument to cells to force the four items onto a single row.

```
. esttab, ///
>     label noobs nonumbers nomtitles               ///
>     cell((                                        ///
>            count(fmt(%9.0fc)  label(Obs.))        ///
>             mean(fmt(%10.3fc) label(Mean))        ///
>              p50(fmt(%8.1fc)  label(Median))      ///
>               sd(fmt(%10.3fc) label(Std. Dev.))   ///
>          ))

------------------------------------------------------------------------
                             Obs.         Mean       Median    Std. Dev.
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Price                      74,000    6,165.257      5,006.5    2,929.519
Repair Record 1978         69,000        3.406          3.0        0.983
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Any idea why `%9.0fc` gives commas for counts, but `%9.3fc` does not?

Comment: Because 74,000.000 is 10 characters in length, so Stata does something to make it fit in 9 characters. Change the 9 to a 10 and the comma returns.